# Calling two ajax functions on form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, sendmail

I have requirement of sending all form parameters as a post request using ajax.
and sending  a mail of parameters to a Email id.

i am following the below procedure for sending post request on form submission.

```
  $.ajax({
      type:post
      url:urlfinal,
      success:function(data){
      }
    });
```

and i am placing mail.php function in action attribute of form element.

But i am facing issue in receiving mail.

So wanted to check whether i can use two url's in a ajax function or do i have to write two ajax functions like below.

```
$.ajax({
      type:post,
      url:urlfinal,
      success:function(data){
      }
    });
  $.ajax({
      url:mail.php,
      success:function(data){
      }
    });
```

`

Comment: No, call `$.ajax` twice.

Comment: Or design your application in a different way, in a way you need 1 call only.

Comment: using $.ajax two times seems don't work?? @sroes

Comment: Show us the code where you say doing it 2 times doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed  by using two ajax function one for sending post request and another one is to send a mail like above.

```
$.ajax({
      type:post,
      url:urlfinal,
      success:function(data){
      }
    });

  $.ajax({
      url:mail.php,
      success:function(data){
      }
    });
```

but still have  doubt why i am facing issue if i use mail.php in action attribute of form element. Any views friends?